# Password in sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, html, sessionstorage

I have a single-page AngularJS app, and authenticate my website via websockets using no cookies. This means a refresh logs the user out. How bad is it to store the password on sessionStorage, so they can refresh during the session? (The username will be in localStorage, and I don't want the full login to persist between sessions).

Thanks!

EDIT:

What I'm more interested in is if there are there any actual security risks for storing in such a way. Is it any less secure than how Chrome stores passwords in plaintext, or how cookies are unencrypted?

Comment: Why not store a session id or token in `sessionStorage` and re-validate on page load?...

Comment: Why would you **not** use a session cookie flagged as [HttpOnly](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly) and [secure](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SecureFlag)? The answers (so far) are just re-inventing a session cookie in a less secure way. If you're going to store the plaintext password, please tell me the site where your app lives so I can avoid going to it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to avoid localstorage, or just cookies?

You could store a session ID in the session storage, and authenticate the user using that, under no circumstances would I store a users password cleartext though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'd want to store the password. You could generate a session token and store that in the sessionStorage. Anyway, if you come to store the password itself, don't store it as plain text.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is... create some hash on your server, and save it on the localStorage.

Send this hash on each request, and the server should validate/handle it, and respond with the appropriate credentials.

But that is also 'not as secure as you may want it to be', so... you can change the hash every x minutes, or have it time out after X minutes of innactivity.

Never store plain text passwords, and never include your hashing algorithm on the client side.

Comment: I get that. But I don't get how it's any more secure. If somebody has access to the device, they can steal all cookies and localstorage, and login anyway. And if they have saved passwords, they too will be visible.

Comment: Isn't that how most websites work? And you are not storing the password, you are storing a hash/session key or whatever you may want to call it.

Comment: Stealing a hash is not as bad as stealing passwords. Sure they can pretend to be an authenticated user on your application, but users can be non-security conscious and just might be re-using passwords on other sites.